# E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-lagui/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Tags: apt

While updating on Ubuntu 16.04 I am getting the error

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-lagui/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Can anyone help me to find out what it is?

Comment: You added a PPA that does not contain packages for 16.04. Remove it.

Comment: W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-lagui/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-lagui/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
THIS IS THE FULL REPORT..

Comment: Just remove that PPA.

Answer (score 0):

- Open `Software & Updates`
- locate the ppa for s-lagui and click once on it
- click the Edit button
- change Distribution from xenial to vivid
- click OK
- close `Software & Updates` and reload database
- if the application at that ppa no longer works in xenial, delete that ppa

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the `vivid` will install?

Comment: @Pilot6 vivid is the last ppa repo available by the author. Whatever software the OP is looking for would be there... now whether that app still works under xenial may be another story, but usually they will. I'll update my answer to include that info.

Comment: Dependencies may be wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 true... but then it won't install, or it won't run... but the 404 error message will be gone.

Comment: Is it better to have applications that won't install / run, or to remove the PPA

Comment: @CharlesGreen The software that was/is at that old PPA may be the only place that it's still available. I have many such PPA's in my own configuration that are for older Ubuntu configurations than my zesty, and I may need to reload one, some day. My way leaves access to the software a possibility, gets rid of the 404 error, and causes no harm especially if the user never needs the software from that PPA. For example, my PPA for dropbox is for xenial, that's the latest, and if I deleted that PPA, I might lose access to reinstalling that app.