# getting error in updating

Tags: updates

I can't update ubuntu mate. Why?
When I try to update it says failed to download repository information.
When I try to update it hangs and is getting stuck.

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/936115/e-failed-to-fetch-http-ppa-launchpad-net-s-lagui-ppa-ubuntu-dists-xenial-main/936123#936123, just change zesty to wily. Please remember to vote for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you are looking at does not have a release for Zesty yet, and as such the update process are complaining that the files you are looking for cannot be found.  You can check the available releases at [the launchpad website](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/icons)

You should remove this PPA from your software sources until it has been updated - a command to do this would be

`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:upubuntu-com/icons`

Comment: icons would still be usable in zesty. See my comment, above.

Comment: after reboot my device started like a kali linux kernal. and i was on ubuntu mate !!! then i again install ubuntu mate.. it show that blue screen like a kali it's did not booted then it goes black screen